# ruby gem update error Enoent

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I have Ruby installed with RubyInstaller on Windows. It was working before but now I can't update any gems and I keep getting errors referring to drive F: which doesn't exist on my machine, I don't know where is this coming from, I can't find any Path variable and running `gem env` there is no reference to a drive F:

```
C:\>gem update --system
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::ENOENT)
    No such file or directory - F:/
```

Update: Please note that I have a roaming profile on my windows machine mapped to a drive F:, but this has always been there and didn't cause a problem

Comment: Did you install it from a USB drive or something like that?

Comment: no .. I have a roaming profile though on my windows machine mapped to drive F: ... but this was always the case and it was working before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with networked drives and root folders.

This is covered in RubyInstaller troubleshooting guide:

https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-network_drive_home

Hope that helps.